# How to select the resultant columns from one of the dataframes while joining with other in Spark?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframes:

```
val df1 = List(("Sid", 1), ("Teni", 2), ("Bob", 3), ("Spark", 4), ("Hbase", 5)).toDF("name", "value")
val df2 = List(("Sidhartha", 1), ("Tammineni", 2), ("Bobby", 3), ("Spark", 4)).toDF("name", "value")
```

After I joined these two dataframes in an outer join, I got the below dataframe as a result.

```
scala> df1.join(df2, Seq("value"), "outer").show()
+-----+---------+-----+---------+-----+
|value|     name|state|     name|state|
+-----+---------+-----+---------+-----+
|    1|      Sid|  odd|      Sid|  odd|
|    3|      Bob|  odd|      Bob|  odd|
|    5|    Hbase|  odd|     null| null|
|    4|    Spark| even|    Spark| even|
|    2|     Teni| even|     Teni| even|
+-----+---------+-----+---------+-----+
```

In order to avoid duplicate columns in the final output, I tried to use

```
df1.join(df2, Seq("name", "state", "value"), "outer").show()
```

But in the result, I see the data coming from `df1`. Even if I tried to join in the other way round as `df2.join(df1, ... outer)`, I still see the output columns of `df1` as below.

```
+---------+-----+-----+
|     name|state|value|
+---------+-----+-----+
|     Teni| even|    2|
|    Spark| even|    4|
|    Hbase|  odd|    5|
|      Bob|  odd|    3|
|      Sid|  odd|    1|
+---------+-----+-----+
```

I tried to select columns from a particular dataframe after join as below:

```
df1.join(df2, Seq("value"), "outer").select(df2("name","value","state")).show()
<console>:28: error: too many arguments (3) for method apply: (colName: String)org.apache.spark.sql.Column in class Dataset
       df1.join(df2, Seq("value"), "outer").select(df2("name","value","state")).show()
```

and

```
scala> df1.join(df2, Seq("value"), "outer").df2("name","value","state").show()
<console>:28: error: value df1 is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
       df1.join(df2, Seq("value"), "outer").df2("name","value","state").show()
```

In this example, I am trying to see the output columns from `df2` after the join operation. Is there anyway I can achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for selecting multiple columns should be to specify each of them one by one, e.g.

```
df1.join(df2, Seq("value"), "outer").select(df2("name"), col("value")).show
+---------+-----+
|     name|value|
+---------+-----+
|Sidhartha|    1|
|    Bobby|    3|
|     null|    5|
|    Spark|    4|
|Tammineni|    2|
+---------+-----+
```

Note that `value` should not be attached to any dataframes, but should be selected using `col`, because it was used as the joining column.

Comment: If there are 6 columns in df2 and want to select all of them from the output, should I write `df1.join(df2, Seq("value"), "outer").select(df2("name"), col("col1", "col2", "col3")).show` ?

Comment: No, you need to write them separately, e.g. `.select(df2("name"), df2("col1"), df2("col2"), df2("col3"))`. Use `df2` instead of `col` because `col1`, `col2`, `col3` are not the joining columns. Only `value` is the joining column, and should be written as `col("value")`.